# expected<true>,but was<false>

Tags: android, junit

I have a small application that converts temperature from *Celsius* to *Fahrenheit* and vice-versa. I have two RadioButtons to select the temperature i.e. Celsius or Fahrenheit and one Button and one EditText . I created a `Junit` to test the application.
Here is my test code:

```
float temparature=102;
Float expected=(float) 0;
solo.enterText(0,String.valueOf(temparature));
solo.clickOnButton("calculate");

         if(solo.isRadioButtonChecked(0)){
            expected=((temparature-32)*5/9);
            }
         else if(solo.isRadioButtonChecked(1)){
          expected=((temparature*9)/5)+32;
                }

         String temp=expected+"";

         assertEquals(true,solo.searchEditText(temp));  

}
```

When I run the above test, test run was successful but failed saying: `expected<true>but was <false>`. I think there is some problem with value rounding. Please let me know what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Also, what does "test run was successfull but failed" mean? How can it be both successfull and failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of expected is probably something like 102.0000001, which is not going to match the text in solo, which should be 102 (if I understand the code correctly).

You should follow the standard float comparison techniques instead of comparing Strings.

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.String,%20double,%20double,%20double%29

So you'd use something like:

```
assertEquals("The converted temperature didn't match.", temparature, expected, 0.001);
```

Overall, it isn't clear what your test case is trying to validate exactly. And the title of your post doesn't indicate anything about the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have  String temp=expected+""; but expected is object(Float) type - Float expected. 
So try expected.toString() or change Float expected to float expected.
And try to debug.